# Html DrawCanvas is null

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to duplicate my canvas but it throw me **drawCanvas is null** error. 
Whenever i hit the button it throw me the error. Is there any other way i can duplicate my canvas?

HTML

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Java Example</Title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
{

if (!window.Clipboard) {
   var pasteCatcher = document.createElement("apDiv1");
   pasteCatcher.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
   pasteCatcher.style.opacity = 0;
   //document.body.appendChild(pasteCatcher);
   pasteCatcher.focus();
   document.addEventListener("click", function() { pasteCatcher.focus(); });
} 

//window.addEventListener("paste", onPasteHandler);

function onPasteHandler(e)
{
    if(e.clipboardData) {
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        if(!items){
            alert("Image Not found");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        if (items[i].kind === 'file' && items[i].type === 'image/png') {
            var blob = items[i].getAsFile(),
                source = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);

            pastedImage = new Image();
            pastedImage.src = source;

            pasteData();
            }
        }
    }
}

function pasteData()
{
    drawCanvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas1');
    ctx = drawCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640,480);
    ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
}

function pasteData2()
{
    drawCanvas = document.getElementById('drawCanvas1');
    ctx = drawCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640,480);
    ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
    image2 = convertCanvasToImage(drawCanvas);
    document.getElementById("canvasHolder").appendChild(image2);
}

 // Converts image to canvas; returns new canvas element
            function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);                
                return canvas;
            }

            // Converts canvas to an image
            function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                return image;
            }
}

        </script>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:258px;
    height:165px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 71px;
    top: 59px;
}
</style>
</Head>

<Body>
<div id="apDiv1" contenteditable='true'>Paste Test</div>
<!--div id='div' contenteditable='true'>Paste</div-->
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<button type="button" value="click me" onclick="return pasteData2();" />
<h2>Canvas Image</h2>
    <p id="canvasHolder">

    </p>
</Body>
</Html>
```

Error
[image]

Comment: We need more information to understand. What kind of error do you get and where ? Getting a canvas by its ID should be working perfectly fine. Can you also show the HTML where you defined your canvas ?
And you are using a global variable for drawCanvas, which is probably gonna give you a bad time

Comment: @Malharhak I'e edit the question and post the entire HTML. I got the error when i clicked the button.

Comment: Well your canvas are created nowhere, and your function that creates a canvas is never called (and doesn't give it the idea of the canvas you're trying to get)

Comment: my pasteData() is working fine. I can see my picture pasted nicely. The problem happens when i clicked the buttton. The error is in pasteData2(). You can try run it in your local and you can see the error once you click the button.

Comment: I don't see any code that calls pasteData, nor creates any of your canvas. So if the code you have written in your post is not the full code you're using, we can't find the problem. Anyway, you are most certainly trying to access an existing canvas, it wouldn't be null otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to register to the image onload event to be sure the image is loaded :

```
     // inside onPastHandler ...

        pastedImage = new Image();
        pastedImage.onload = pasteData.bind(null,pastedImage);
        pastedImage.src = source;
```

Then you are mentionning a non-existent canvas, 'drawCanvas1', that you don't
even need :

```
function pasteData(img) {
      document.getElementById("canvasHolder").appendChild(img);
 }
```

Comment: my pasteData() is working fine. I can see my picture paste nicely. The problem happens when i clicked the buttton. The error is in pasteData2(). You can try run it in your local and you can see the error once you click the button.